# Django form field not displaying correct queryset values

Tags: python, django

The following code is from an multi-vendor ecommerce portal. We need to display different shipping methods according to the store(or vendor) on the checkout summary page.

However even though I get correct queryset while print i.e Store 1 has Test Rest of World Shipping method and Store 2 has UPC and DHL, the rendered form shows incorrect values - [image: page screenshot]

```
#########################################################
class ShippingCountryChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):

    widget = forms.RadioSelect()

    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        price_html = format_price(obj.price.gross, obj.price.currency)
        label = mark_safe('%s %s' % (obj.shipping_method, price_html))
        return label


class ShippingMethodForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, country_code, *args, **kwargs):
        stores = kwargs.pop('stores')
        super(ShippingMethodForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for count, store in enumerate(stores, start=1):
            method_field = ShippingCountryChoiceField(
            queryset=ShippingMethodCountry.objects.select_related(
                'shipping_method').order_by('price').filter(shipping_method__store=store),
            label=pgettext_lazy('Shipping method form field label', 'Shipping method for %s' % store),
            required=True)
            if country_code:
                queryset = method_field.queryset
                method_field.queryset = queryset.unique_for_country_code(country_code)
            if self.initial.get('method') is None:
                method_field.initial = method_field.queryset.first()
            method_field.empty_label = None
            self.fields['method_%d' % count] = method_field
        print [q.queryset for q in self.fields.values()]



###################################################
@load_checkout
@validate_voucher
@validate_cart
@validate_is_shipping_required
@validate_shipping_address
@add_voucher_form
def shipping_method_view(request, checkout):
    country_code = checkout.shipping_address.country.code
    stores = checkout.cart.lines.values_list('variant__product__store', flat=True)
    stores = Store.objects.filter(id__in=stores)
    print checkout.shipping_method
    shipping_method_form = ShippingMethodForm(
        country_code, request.POST or None, initial={'method': checkout.shipping_method},
        stores=stores)
    if shipping_method_form.is_valid():
        for count, store in enumerate(stores):
            checkout.shipping_method[store] = shipping_method_form.cleaned_data['method_%s' % count]
        return redirect('checkout:summary')
    print [q.queryset for q in shipping_method_form.fields.values()]
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'checkout/shipping_method.html', context={
        'shipping_method_form': shipping_method_form, 'checkout': checkout})
##############################################################

{% extends "checkout/details.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load gross from prices_i18n %}
{% load bootstrap_form from bootstrap3 %}

{% block forms %}
    <h3>{% trans "Shipping address" context "Checkout shipping address title" %}</h3>
    {% include "userprofile/snippets/address-short.html" with address=checkout.shipping_address only %}
    <p><a href="{% url 'checkout:shipping-address' %}">{% trans "Select other address" %}</a></p>
    <hr>
    <form method="post" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% bootstrap_form shipping_method_form show_label=True %}
        <p class="text-md-right">
            <button type="submit" class="btn primary">
                {% trans "Continue" context "Checkout shipping method primary action" %}
            </button>
        </p>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: what are the correct values?

Comment: I have edited the question for your answer -  Store 1 has Test Rest of World Shipping method and Store 2 has UPC and DHL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are instantiating the widget in the field definition. This could cause state to be shared between different fields. Try changing it to:

```
class ShippingCountryChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):

    widget = forms.RadioSelect
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you @alasdair